# Cannot find symbol - method scroll()

Tags: java, greenfoot

I am working on a simple Mario side-scroller, and When I try to call the Scrolling objects' **scroll()** method, I get the **Cannot find symbol - method scroll()** error thrown. Please help!
 **Here is the Subworld file**

```
import greenfoot.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
/**
 * Write a description of class MarioWorld here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a 


public class MarioWorld extends World
{
    ArrayList<MovingActor> moving = new ArrayList<MovingActor>();
    ArrayList<Actor> things = new ArrayList<Actor>();
    Message messagebox = new Message("");
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class MarioWorld.
     * 
     */
    public MarioWorld()
    {
        super(800, 600, 1);
        for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
            {
                things.add(new GreenApple());
                things.add(new Shamrock());

            }
            for(int i = 0; i<8;i++)
                things.add(new Brick());
            moving.add(new Mario());
            for(int r = 0;r < things.size();r++)
            {
                addObject(things.get(r),Greenfoot.getRandomNumber(800),Greenfoot.getRandomNumber(600));
            }
    }
    public void act()
    {

       for(int i = 0;i < things.size();i++)
            {
                things.get(i).scroll();
            }
            addObject(moving.get(0),15,300);
            moving.get(0).worldact();
    }


}
`
```

**Here is one of the 3 scrolling classes(they are identical except for Name/picture**

```
 import greenfoot.*;
public class Shamrock extends Actor implements Scrollable
{
    /**
     * Act - do whatever the Shamrock wants to do. This method is called whenever
     * the 'Act' or 'Run' button gets pressed in the environment.
     */

    public Actor worldact()
    {
        scroll();
        return this;
    }
    public void scroll()
    {
        int x = getX();
        int y = getY(); 
        if(x <= 0)
            x = 800;
        x -= 6;
        setLocation(x,y);

    }
}
```

**Here is the 'Scrollable' interface**

```
import greenfoot.*;

public interface Scrollable  
{
 public void scroll();
}
```

Comment: I won't attempt an answer, but I think you might have to explicitly cast, e.g. `((Shamrock)things.get(i)).scroll();`

Comment: is an actor a class tht implements scrollable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `moving` is a `object` of `ArrayList`  not `Shamrock` so you can call only `arraylist` Class method with `moving` Object like `add()` `remove()`.

Here ArrayList`is generic type Safed`arraylist`. So, you need to remove the`object`from the arraylist then only try to apply method`Scroll()`

Use this code

```
((Shamrock)things.get(i)).scroll();
```

instead of `things.get(i).scroll();`

Answer (score 0):

`things` is a list of `Actor`. `Actor` doesn't implement `Scollable`, but `Shamrock` does. `things.get(i)` returns `Actor` which doesn't have `Scollable.scroll()`. You need to cast it to either `Shamrock` or `Scollable`. Or you can make `things` a list of `Shamrock`.